# Estimating Kelley Skewness

Tags: skewness, unbiased-estimator, estimators

Groeneveld *et al* have proposed the following measure of Skewness:

$$\mathcal S(x, u) = \frac{F^{-1}(u; x) + F^{-1}(1 - u; x) - 2 F^{-1}(1/2; x)}{F^{-1}(u; x) - F^{-1}(1-u; x)}$$

where $F^{-1}(u; x)$ is the inverse cumulative distribution of the random variable $x$ and $ \frac{1}{2} \lt u \lt 1.$ For $u=0.9$ this becomes Kelley's measure of Skewness.

What are common estimators of $\mathcal S(x, u)$ for a choice of $u$? What is the efficiency/bias trade-off I might face?

Comment: This formula looks misquoted to me. $(Q_{90} - Q_{50})  - (Q_{50} - Q_{10})$ compares the length of right and left tails and simplifies to $Q_{90} - 2 Q_{50} + Q_{10}$ so the last sign looks wrong. It is easy to imagine that you might then want to scale by $Q_{90} - Q_{10}$ but I can't see that adding a factor $Q_{10} / Q_{90}$ makes sense either dimensionally or statistically. Kelly is probably also a common mutation on Kelley. Can you give a source for this formula? At best it is a variant on Bowley's measure (often misattributed to Galton), at worst someone is very confused.

Comment: Whether this is a biased or unbiased estimator of the corresponding population quantity across any or all distributions is a different question.

Comment: @NickCox My source was http://www.statisticshowto.com/kellys-measure-of-skewness/, but I've since searched for "Kelley" and am updating the question

Comment: The Kelley [sic] concerned was Truman Lee Kelley and the source appears to be his book 1923. _Statistical method_. New York: Macmillan. More crucially, your site [cite!] (thanks) makes it clear that we have here sloppy use of parentheses P90 – 2*P50 + P10 / P90 – P10 should be (P90 – 2*P50 + P10) / (P90 – P10).

Comment: To comment on the question: linear combinations of quantiles are usually well behaved but once you're calculating ratios, exact analytical results are typically hard to get. I've not seen anything but people proposing to use sample quantiles as estimates of the corresponding quantiles; what grounds would there be for anything else?  If you want to know how that works I would suggest bootstrapping or simulation from known distributions.

Comment: The Groeneveld et al. reference is not given here, but  David, F.N. and Johnson, N.L. 1956. Some tests of significance with ordered variables. _Journal, Royal Statistical Society_ B 18: 1-20 is a source for the general idea. A.L. Bowley used the measure for quartiles ($u = 0.25$). It was Richard Groeneveld who tracked down Bowley's introduction of that measure in the 1902 edition of his _Elements of Statistics_.

Comment: On p.77 of his _Statistical Method_ see the equivalent of P50 - (P90 + P10)/2. Comments: 1. This is not dimensionless or unit-free but has the same units as the original data. 2. It is zero whenever P50 = (P90 + P10)/2 as is expected of any symmetric distribution and some asymmetric distributions. 3. More surprisingly, this is negative whenever P90 is further from P50 than is P10, and positive if the opposite is true. That is the wrong way round compared with convention on how skewness is signed. In sum, Kelley's measure of skewness as cited is not Kelley's original measure.